# ChilkatHttpRequest converting CR to CRLF when using LoadBodyFromString

Tags: httprequest, chilkat

I'm using the ActiveX component.  I'm not sure if it is happening in other component versions.

I'm removing the LF chars from my string before calling LoadBodyFromString but when I post the data to the web service it is reporting that the line endings are CRLF and are invalid.  It is expecting just CR.

Is anyone else having this?  Is there a setting I can use to prevent my data from being modified?  Is there another way I should be loading the data into the request object?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's actually converting the CR to LF rather than CRLF from what I can see.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if this happens in the latest version of Chilkat.  I quickly checked if I could see anything obvious that would indicate this is happening, but didn't find anything.

Comment: I'm using v9.5.0.76.  I will use wireshark to confirm that this is what is going on just to be sure.  It could be an issue on the receiving end.

Comment: Ok... I just wrote my own script to post to and the data that was posted was exactly like I sent it.  The prob is on the government web service that I'm posting to.  I should have known it was on their end.  I apologize for wasting your time like this.  I do appreciate the response.